# Android RecyclerView does not animate all the items

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, adapter

in my application i have made a Recyclerview with selection mode.
When the user choose to start the selection mode i call             notifyDataSetChanged();

and from onBindViewHolder()
i call a method to animate the layout item a little bit right to expose a check box so the user could check/choose the items.

my problem is when i scroll up or down there is 1-3 items that
the animation does not effect them
how can i handle or fix it?.

here is an example of my code:

**Adapter:**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {

      if(startSelectionMode()){
            holder.openAnimation();
        }else{
            holder.closeAnimation();
        }      
    }
```

**ViewHolder:**

```
public void openAnimation() {
    containerView.animate().translationX(checkBox.getWidth()).setDuration(300).start();
}

public void closeAnimation() {
    containerView.animate().translationX(0).setDuration(300).start();

}
```

Comment: may i provide you some modified code that works for animation or you need to modify this code

Comment: i will be glad to get modified code that works, and any example of working animation when scrolling and etc..

Comment: check my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Add below code in your **adapter** class and modify your Object class name with StudentBean.

add this on your adapter class at global variable

```
private Integer previousPosition = 0;
```

.

```
public StudentBean removeItem(int position) {
    final StudentBean model = mModels.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    return model;
}

public void addItem(int position, StudentBean model) {
    mModels.add(position, model);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    final StudentBean model = mModels.remove(fromPosition);
    mModels.add(toPosition, model);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}

public void animateTo(List<StudentBean> models) {
    applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
    applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
    applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
}

private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<StudentBean> newModels) {
    for (int i = mModels.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final StudentBean model = mModels.get(i);
        if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
            removeItem(i);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<StudentBean> newModels) {
    for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
        final StudentBean model = newModels.get(i);
        if (!mModels.contains(model)) {
            addItem(i, model);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<StudentBean> newModels) {
    for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
        final StudentBean model = newModels.get(toPosition);
        final int fromPosition = mModels.indexOf(model);
        if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
            moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

do this at last in your onBindViewHolder method

```
 if (position > previousPosition) {
            AnimationUtils.animate(holder, true);
        } else {
            AnimationUtils.animate(holder, false);
        }
        previousPosition = position;
```

this will be your AnimationUtils class

```
public class AnimationUtils {
    private static int counter = 0;

    public static void scaleXY(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setScaleX(0);
        holder.itemView.setScaleY(0);

        PropertyValuesHolder propx = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1);
        PropertyValuesHolder propy = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1);

        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(holder.itemView, propx, propy);


        animator.setDuration(800);
        animator.start();
    }

    public static void scaleX(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setScaleX(0);

        PropertyValuesHolder propx = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1);

        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(holder.itemView, propx);


        animator.setDuration(800);
        animator.start();
    }

    public static void scaleY(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setScaleY(0);

        PropertyValuesHolder propy = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1);

        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(holder.itemView, propy);

        animator.setDuration(800);
        animator.start();
    }

    public static void animate(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, boolean goesDown) {

       /* YoYo.with(Techniques.RubberBand)
                .duration(1000)
                .playOn(holder.itemView);*/
//        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
//        ObjectAnimator animatorScaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "scaleX" ,0.5F, 0.8F, 1.0F);
//        ObjectAnimator animatorScaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "scaleY", 0.5F, 0.8F, 1.0F);
        ObjectAnimator animatorTranslateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationY", goesDown == true ? 300 : -300, 0);
//        ObjectAnimator animatorTranslateX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationX", -50, 50, -30, 30, -20, 20, -5, 5, 0);
//        animatorSet.playTogether(animatorTranslateX, animatorTranslateY, animatorScaleX, animatorScaleY);
//        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator());
//        animatorSet.setDuration(1000);
//        animatorSet.start();
        animatorTranslateY.setDuration(1000);
        animatorTranslateY.start();

    }

    public static void animateToolbarDroppingDown(View containerToolbar) {

        containerToolbar.setRotationX(-90);
        containerToolbar.setAlpha(0.2F);
        containerToolbar.setPivotX(0.0F);
        containerToolbar.setPivotY(0.0F);
        Animator alpha = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(containerToolbar, "alpha", 0.2F, 0.4F, 0.6F, 0.8F, 1.0F).setDuration(4000);
        Animator rotationX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(containerToolbar, "rotationX", -90, 60, -45, 45, -10, 30, 0, 20, 0, 5, 0).setDuration(8000);
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animatorSet.playTogether(alpha, rotationX);
        animatorSet.start();
    }

    /**
     * Courtesy: Vladimir Topalovic
     *
     * @param holder
     * @param goesDown
     */
    public static void animate1(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, boolean goesDown) {
        int holderHeight = holder.itemView.getHeight();
        holder.itemView.setPivotY(goesDown == true ? 0 : holderHeight);
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        ObjectAnimator animatorTranslateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationY", goesDown == true ? 300 : -300, 0);
        ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "scaleY", 1f, 0.4f, 1f);
        ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "scaleX", 1f, 1.3f, 1f);
        animatorTranslateY.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        scaleY.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
        scaleX.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
        animatorSet.play(animatorTranslateY).before(scaleY).before(scaleX);
        animatorSet.setDuration(700);
        animatorSet.start();
    }

    /**
     * Courtesy: Vladimir Topalovic
     *
     * @param holder
     * @param goesDown
     */
    public static void animateSunblind(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, boolean goesDown) {
        int holderHeight = holder.itemView.getHeight();
        holder.itemView.setPivotY(goesDown == true ? 0 : holderHeight);
        holder.itemView.setPivotX(holder.itemView.getHeight());
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        ObjectAnimator animatorTranslateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationY", goesDown == true ? 300 : -300, 0);
        ObjectAnimator animatorRotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "rotationX", goesDown == true ? -90f : 90, 0f);
        ObjectAnimator animatorScaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "scaleX", 0.5f, 1f);
        animatorSet.playTogether(animatorTranslateY, animatorRotation, animatorScaleX);
        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1.1f));
        animatorSet.setDuration(1000);
        animatorSet.start();
    }

    /**
     * Courtesy: Vladimir Topalovic
     *
     * @param holder
     * @param goesDown
     */
    public static void animateScatter(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, boolean goesDown) {
        counter = ++counter % 4;
        int holderHeight = holder.itemView.getHeight();
        int holderWidth = holder.itemView.getWidth();
        View holderItemView = holder.itemView;
        holderItemView.setPivotY(goesDown == true ? 0 : holderHeight);
        holderItemView.setPivotX(holderWidth / 2);
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        ObjectAnimator animatorTranslateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holderItemView, "translationY", goesDown == true ? 300 : -300, 0);
        ObjectAnimator animatorTranslateX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holderItemView, "translationX", counter == 1 || counter == 3 ? holderWidth : -holderWidth, 0);
        ObjectAnimator animatorScaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holderItemView, "scaleX", counter == 1 || counter == 2 ? 0 : 2, 1f);
        ObjectAnimator animatorScaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holderItemView, "scaleY", counter == 1 || counter == 2 ? 0 : 2, 1f);
        ObjectAnimator animatorAlpha = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holderItemView, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
        animatorAlpha.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.5f));
        animatorSet.playTogether(animatorAlpha, animatorScaleX, animatorScaleY, animatorTranslateX, animatorTranslateY);
        animatorSet.setDuration(2000).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1.1f));
        animatorSet.start();
    }

//        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationY", (positive == true ? 200.0F : -200.F), 0F);
//        objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
//        objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
//        objectAnimator.start();
//        YoYo.with(Techniques.StandUp).duration(800).playOn(holder.itemView);
//        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
//        Animator scaleVertical = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView,"scaleY",1.0F,0.8F,1.2F,1.4F,1.6F,1.4F,1.2F,0.8F,1.0F).setDuration(2000);
//        Animator rotateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView,"rotationY",0,5,10,15,20,25,30,25,20,15,10,5,0).setDuration(2000);
//        //ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView,"scaleY",1.0F,0.8F,1.2F,1.4F,1.6F,1.4F,1.2F,0.8F,1.0F).setDuration(2000)
//        //ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView,"rotationY",0,5,10,15,20,25,30,25,20,15,10,5,0).setDuration(2000);
//
//        animatorSet.playTogether(rotateY, scaleVertical);
//        animatorSet.start();


//
}
```